# 18.04 server: How to enable xfce4 from boot instead of console

Tags: command-line, 18.04, xfce, gui

Any clue on how to enable my ubuntu server 18.04 to boot the xfce4 gui instead of the CLI thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install XFCE4 into your 18.04 server with

`sudo apt-get install xfce4 slim`

then start that with

`sudo service slim start`